# tools to code generate python from existing database?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, code-generation

Please forgive my ignorance I am new to Python development.

Is there a tool to create Python code from an existing database (e.g. mySQL, Postgresql)

For example, if I have a database designed with sample data inside (I have tables, functions, and data established in a database) is there any code generator tools that will help me to generate some of the python code (e.g. classes/entities, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM).  One popular ORM for Python is [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Comment: SQLAlchemy is built into pyramid correct? I haven't used it, but I thought SQLAlchemy takes the classes/entities and makes the database tables... so that would be the opposite of what I need it to do.. but I am not familiar with SQLAlchemy... is this the case?

Comment: Actually, SQLAlchemy can swing both ways. See http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/10/sqlalchemy-connecting-to-pre-existing-databases/.

Answer (score 2):

To generate object relational mapper (ORM) models from a pre-existing SQL database, a tool that you may find useful is the Python module [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/) or forked [flask-sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/flask-sqlacodegen/)

These will allow you to build a map of the database on your local disk, to be used with SQLAlchemy and/or Flask.

I have posted here as I stumbled across your question whilst I was looking for these modules.